# which averaging should be used when computing the ROC AUC on imbalanced data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a binary classification task on imbalanced data set .. and right now computing the ROC AUC using : 
`sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average='macro')` [source](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html)
and I have two questions:

- I am not sure if the averaging `macro` is influenced by the class imbalance here and what is the best averaging in this situation (when classifying imbalanced classes)?
- Is there a reference for the way that shows how scikit-learn calculate the ROC AUC with the different averaging argument ?

Comment: This is off-topic, rather on-topic in stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

If your target variable is binary, then `average` does not make sense and is ignored. See  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/metrics/base.py#L76 and also the comment in the doc: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e92acf49d46251479b75c88cba632de1937/sklearn/metrics/base.py#L52

Answer (score 1):

Using `average='macro'` is the reasonable way to go. Hopefully, you already trained your model with consideration of the data's imbalance. So now, when evaluating performance, you want to give both classes the same weight.

For example, if your set consists of 90% positive examples, and let's say the roc auc for the positive label is 0.8, and the roc auc for the negative label is 0.4. Using `average='weighted'` will produce an average roc auc of 0.8 * 0.9 + 0.4 * 0.1 = 0.76. Obviously, it is mostly affected by the positive label's score. Using `average='macro'` will result in a score that gives the minority label (0) equal weight. In this case, 0.6.

To conclude, if you don't care much about precision and recall relating to the negative label, use `average='weighted'`. Otherwise, use `average='macro'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `average='weighted'` is your choice for the problem of imbalanced classes
as it follows from 3.3.2.1 in

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: I tried changing the average but is always gives me the same value any idea why ? I put how i calculate it in the main question and it is for a binary classification problem.